# How to write JavaScript which works normally in Chrome and IE?

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

```
function popupaddpackage(urlToOpen){
  var window_width = screen.availWidth/2;
  var window_height = screen.availHeight;
  var window_left = (screen.availWidth/2)-(window_width/2);
  var window_top = (screen.availHeight/2)-(window_height/2);
  var winParms = "Status=yes" + ",resizable=yes" + ",height="+window_height+",width="+window_width + ",left="+window_left+",top="+window_top;
  var newwindow = window.open(urlToOpen,'_blank',winParms);
  newwindow.focus();
}

<a href="" onclick="popupaddpackage('popupchange.jsp?extkey=<%=extKey%>&classId=<%=classid%>')">OPEN POPUP</a>
```

I use this js function to open pop up screen in my jsp, and this works normally in Chrome but in IE doesn't work normally. In Chrome - pop up screen opens and the page behind remains stable, but in IE - pop up screen opens and the page behind redirects to index.jsp (the page behind is property.jsp). How to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please, [launch JS pop-ups the *right* way](http://www.ianhoar.com/2010/09/26/doing-javascript-popup-windows-the-right-way) and the problem should be gone.

In your case, it would be something like:

```
function popupaddpackage(link) {
  var window_width = screen.availWidth/2;
  var window_height = screen.availHeight;
  var window_left = (screen.availWidth/2)-(window_width/2);
  var window_top = (screen.availHeight/2)-(window_height/2);
  var winParms = "Status=yes" + ",resizable=yes" + ",height="+window_height+",width="+window_width + ",left="+window_left+",top="+window_top;
  var newwindow = window.open(link.href,link.target,winParms);
  newwindow.focus();
}
```

And for the HTML:

```
<a href="popupchange.jsp?extkey=<%=extKey%>&classId=<%=classid%>" target="_blank" onclick="popupaddpackage(this);return false;">OPEN POPUP</a>
```

That way, you:

1. cleanly separate *logic* from *markup*
2. help search engines understand (index) your page correctly
3. users without javascript can also open the page without problems

Comment: I wrote which you write. But it opens popup in new tab. how to make it open in new window?

Comment: sorry, I forgot an adaptation for your specific case. does it work now?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `return false` to the last line of `popupaddpackage(urlToOpen)`? For SEO reasons it may be advantageous to put a URL in the `href` and what is JavaScript is disabled?

Comment: in other words: [**do. the. right. way.**](http://www.ianhoar.com/2010/09/26/doing-javascript-popup-windows-the-right-way) :)

Answer (score -1):

Change the href attribute to `href="#"`

Answer (score -1):

Another way of fixing it would be

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="...your function ... ">OPEN POPUP</a>
```

Comment: bad, bad, BAD idea! that dirty way won't work in browsers that don't support the `javascript:` pseudo-protocol or don't have JS. Use the [right way](http://www.ianhoar.com/2010/09/26/doing-javascript-popup-windows-the-right-way). **DISCLAIMER: I don't have any commission for promoting this page! :)**